# Performance issue with lots of images in scrolledpane

Tags: wxpython

I want to create a scrolled pane with hundreds of images. My code runs OK until 200 images, but for larger number of images, starts to go very slow. On a Core i9, this code (just a stripped down version of what I'm actually doing) takes almost 20 seconds to display. Any idea how I could improve?

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

class ImgPanel(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ImgPanel, self).__init__(parent, 
                                       style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)


        self.imgSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)   
        for i in range(500):
            image = wx.Bitmap('chrome.png')
            bitmap=wx.StaticBitmap(parent=self)
            bitmap.SetBitmap(image)
            self.imgSizer.Add(bitmap, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.imgSizer)

        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.SetupScrolling()
        self.IsRectReady = False
        self.newRectPara=[0,0,0,0]

class  MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, width, height):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, 
                                       title=title,
                                       size=(width, height))

        self.imgPanel = ImgPanel(self)
        self.frameSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)        
        self.frameSizer.Add(self.imgPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)        
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.SetSizer(self.frameSizer)
        self.Layout()      

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)        
def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None, "test", 1200, 800)
    app.SetTopWindow(frame) 
    app.MainLoop()

if "__main__" == __name__ :
    main()
```

Comment: Try loading only as many as will fit in the first few visible pages, then load others on scroll down, until they are all loaded.

Comment: Or use wx.lib.agw.thumbnailctrl

Comment: @Rolf of Saxony Thanks, that's what I'm gonna do. I also plan on removing/destroying the ones that go out of the screen on scroll down or up. My first tests show that I could virtually load thousands of elements this way, without memory leak of performance drop down.

Comment: @Infinity77: In this case, I guess it would work, but you couldn't use it for more generic widgets.